# Category of presheaves and logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, propositional-calculus, intuitionistic-logic, cartesian-closed-categories

Let ${\bf C}$ be a small category.  As is well known, the category of presheaves ${\bf Set^C}$ is cartesian closed: it can be a model of intuitionistic propositional logic.

Can it also be a model of classical propositional logic?

That is, does ${\bf Set^C}$ always have an arrow $\bot^{(\bot^A)} \rightarrow A$ for each object $A$? (where $\bot$ denotes an initial object of ${\bf Set^C}$)

Comment: Note: "the category of presheaves" usually refers to $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}^{\text{op}}}$.

Comment: If you take any Krikpe frame disproving double negation elimination, then set $\mathbf{C}$ to be the category for that frame's poset $K$, then you automatically get an example of an object $A$ of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}}$ with no such arrow (take the presheaf which maps $k \in K$ to $\{ 0 \}$ if $k \Vdash p$ and which maps $k$ to $\emptyset$ otherwise).  On the other hand, it's certainly *possible* for $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}}$ to be a model of classical propositional logic for particular choices of $\mathbf{C}$, e.g. if $\mathbf{C}$ is a discrete category.

Comment: For a concrete counterexample, consider where $\mathbf{C}$ is the category corresponding to the poset $\{ 0, 1 \}$ with $0 < 1$; and $A$ is the presheaf mapping $0 \mapsto \emptyset, 1 \mapsto \{ 0 \}$ (with the unique possible maps as the action of the functor on morphisms).  Then, you should be able to calculate that $\bot^A \simeq \bot$ is the initial presheaf, and $\bot^{(\bot^A)} \simeq 1$ is the presheaf sending each object to a singleton; so there is no morphism $\bot^{(\bot^A)} \to A$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the comments.  I understood that there is no natural transformation from 1 to A because there is no map from 1(0) = {*} to A(0) (= the empty set).

Comment: You may like to verify the following: the category of presheaves on a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a boolean category (= every subobject has a complement) if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ is a groupoid.

Comment: @ZhenLin This should be an answer.

Comment: When I have said that "$\bf Set^C$ is a model of classical propositional logic",
I have meant that objects are propositions and arrows are deductive relations
(of classical logic).

However, when we say that "$\bf Set^C$ is a Boolean category",
we are thinking of the algebra of subobjects of $\bf Set^C$.

Are the two concepts the same thing?

Comment: @DanielSchepler It seems to me that even if $\bf C$ is a groupoid or a discrete category, there exists a case where there is no arrow (natural transformation) from $\bot^{(\bot^A)}$ to $A$.

Suppose $\bf C$ is $\{X, Y\}$ and its only arrows are identities. By letting $A \in {\bf Set^C}$ be such that $A(X)=\emptyset$ and $A(Y)=\{*\}$, we have that $\bot^{(\bot^A)} = 1$. In this setting, we cannot define any natural transformation from $1$ to $A$ since there is no map from $1(X)=\{*\}$ to $A(X)=\emptyset$ in $\bf Set$.

Comment: In the example you gave, $\bot^A(X) = \emptyset$ and $\bot^A(Y) = \{*\}$, and $\bot^{(\bot^A)}(X) = \{*\}$ and $\bot^{(\bot^A)}(Y) = \emptyset$.  More generally, if $\mathbf{C}$ is a discrete category, then you can calculate the exponential in $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf{C}}$ "pointwise": $B^A(X)$ is canonically isomorphic to the exponential in $\mathbf{Set}$, $B(X)^{A(X)}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  In the example above I have set $A(X)=\emptyset$ and $A(Y)=\{*\}$.  In your explanation, $X$ and $Y$ seem interchanged; if so, I think I could understand.

Comment: Right, sorry, I did get them switched around.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Thanks, it was helpful.